# Android NDK permission denied on include that contains variable

Tags: android, android-ndk

This fails:

```
JNIPATH := $(call my-dir)   
LOCAL_PATH := $(JNIPATH)

include $(JNIPATH)/otherfile.mk 

D:\dev\/src/android/jni/Android.mk:62:
D:\dev\/src/android/jni: Permission denied
D:\dev\/src/android/jni/Android.mk:62: /otherfile.mk: No such file or directory
```

However, if I replace `$(JNIPATH)` with the full, relative path to `otherfile.mk` (gleaned from using `$(warning $(JNIPATH))` in the build script), it works.

Only possible conclusion: including with a variable is the issue.

Tested on NDK r10d and r8e.  Using Windows 8.1 host.  Not using Cygwin command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

This was happening because there is an invisible tab at the end of the first line.

The include macro accepts multiple arguments, and saw `D:\dev\/src/android/jni` as the first file to be included.  As this is a directory and the error diagnostic is extremely coarse, it rejected it with permission denied.

Soul crushing way to lose an hour, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: I'd kiss you if i could! Just a f*****g space in the end of line!